# Notepad++ plugin exception

Tags: plugins, notepad++

I am developing a notepad++ plugin in c++ by using Visual Studio 2013. I put my plugin's dll to the notepad++ plugin directory. When i try to run my plugin in notepad+ menu, it gives "Unknown exception" with window title: PluginsManager::runPluginCommand Exception. How can solve it? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have not (yet) found a way to replace or to add more details to the "Unknown exception" message, but I do have a workaround.

For exceptions raised at plugin startup I surrounded the `PluginBase.SetCommand(...);` call with a `try...catch...`:

```
try {
    PluginBase.SetCommand(...);
}
catch ( Exception ex )
{
    Win32.SendMessage(PluginBase.GetCurrentScintilla(),
       SciMsg.SCI_INSERTTEXT, -1,
       "Exception at startup in <name of my plugin>: " + ex.ToString());
}
```

I do not recommend this for the final version of a plugin, but it can help with getting the plugin working. My reasons for not recommending it are:

- It catches every exception.
- It writes the exception message into the
  current buffer. It would be easy to not notice the exception message,
  to assume that the plugin worked, and hence to corrupt the contents
  of the file being edited.

The same technique can be used with the methods called when the plugin is executed.